# Testing Amazon Translate API with Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, translate

I'm trying to test Amazon Translate Services using Postman. When I send my post request, I get the error:

> Could not send request -- Error: Request timed out

In the "Authorization" tab, I selected "AWS Signature" and entered my AccessKey, SecretKey, and AWS Region.

In the "Headers" tab, I entered:

```
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Date: 20180820T184626Z
Z-Amz-Target: AWSShineFrontendService_20170701.TranslateText
```

In the "Body" tab, I entered:

```
{
  "SourceLanguageCode": "en",
  "TargetLanguageCode": "fr",
  "Text": "this is a test"
}
```

I tried to increase my timeout in settings and that did not help.

Any help would be appreciated!